# Issues with Formatting a Table for Integers Modulo 9

Tags: tables, amsmath

I'm having some trouble formatting a table in LaTeX. I'm trying to format a table for the addition of the Integers modulo 9, but it isn't working correctly.

This is what I currently have:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c c c c c c c c c }
$+_9$ & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\
[1] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] \\
[2] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [6] & [0] & [1] \\
[3] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [6] & [1] & [2] \\
[4] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [6] & [2] & [3] \\
[5] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [6] & [3] & [4] \\
[6] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] \\
[7] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [6] & [5] & [6] \\
[8] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This, for reasons I can't quite figure out, isn't working. However, if I only do the first two rows, like so:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c c c c c c c c c }
$+_9$ & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

It works just fine. Would anyone happen to know what's wrong?

Comment: Just enclose the `[i]`s of the first column within `{ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linebreak thinks the `[1]` (or whatever) that follows is an optional argument, unless you tell it to stop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c|c c c c c c c c c }
$+_9$ & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] \\\relax
[1] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] \\\relax
[2] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [6] & [0] & [1] \\\relax
[3] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [6] & [1] & [2] \\\relax
[4] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [6] & [2] & [3] \\\relax
[5] & [5] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [6] & [3] & [4] \\\relax
[6] & [6] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] \\\relax
[7] & [7] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [6] & [5] & [6] \\\relax
[8] & [8] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] & [6] & [7]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I'm still receiving an error message. It's telling me "Misplaced \noalign" where the "\hline" is.

Comment: @MrM21632 Remove the first `\relax` at line 5.

Comment: Yes, remove the first one. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `\halign`:

```
\def\pdig#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{[#1] [#2] [#3] [#4] [#5] [#6] [#7] [#8] [#9]}
\def\trule{\vrule height10pt depth4pt\relax}
\vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil#\hfil\trule\ &\pdig#\cr
$+_9$ & 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 \cr
\noalign{\hrule}
[0]   & 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 \cr
[1]   & 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0 \cr
[2]   & 2  3  4  5  6  7  6  0  1 \cr
[3]   & 3  4  5  6  7  8  6  1  2 \cr
[4]   & 4  5  6  7  8  0  6  2  3 \cr
[5]   & 5  6  7  8  0  1  6  3  4 \cr
[6]   & 6  7  8  0  1  2  3  4  5 \cr
[7]   & 7  8  0  1  2  3  6  5  6 \cr
[8]   & 8  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 \cr
}}
```